# DOS Batch Command file - iterative processing

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I was happily using the following windows command batch .BAT to move files, and yesterday from some unknown reason it stopped working. 
The file good.txt which this command batch calls contains a list of JPG files:
123.jpg
456.jpg
etc...
The folder on which this batch is run contains .CR2 files with the same names. This program simply copies the corresponding CR2 files to the "good" directory.

Do you know why it is not working anymore? I get an incorrect syntax error.

Thanks

Blaise

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call :movetodir Good
goto :end
:movetodir
set textfile=%1.txt
set writetodirectory=%1
md !writetodirectory!
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%G in (!textfile!) do (
set filejpg=%%G
set fileraw=!filejpg:jpg=CR2!
move !fileraw! "!writetodirectory!"
)   
goto :eof
:end
```

Comment: What has changed?  Do you get information about where or what the syntax error is?  Have you tried commenting out some lines of code using `REM` until you don't get a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to isolate which command is actually causing the problem. Change the first line to:

```
rem @echo off
```

and run it from a command prompt. The point where the error occurs should narrow it down quite a bit.

It would also be useful to see the contents of your `good.txt` file, on the off chance there may be something "wrong" with the file names, such as if they contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
move !fileraw! "!writetodirectory!"
```

to

```
move "!fileraw!" "!writetodirectory!"
```

would be my initial guess - since your FOR loop appears to be using `tokens=*` to get the filenames.

Note that `"tokens=* delims= "` will simply suppress leading spaces. `"delims="` will apply the value of the line literally, including any (probably non-existent) leading spaces.

But it's a little difficult to say unless you specify what the exact error message is. `ECHO`ing `%%G` at the beginning of the loop (possibly with obvious "fence characters" surrounding it) would be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several characters which will break the code that you have posted.
I'm making the assumption that the code is complete - then this code below should perform the same task but be more robust with spaces and ! & characters.

```
@echo off
call :movetodir Good
goto :EOF
:movetodir
md "%~1" 2>nul
for /f "delims=" %%G in (' type "%~1.txt" ') do (
echo moving "%%~nG.CR2"
move "%%~nG.CR2" "%~1" >nul
)
```

Comment: Added the original call statement.